# Regex in Python Equation Replacement

Tags: python, regex

I'm somewhat new to regex and Python and am in the following situation. I'd like to take an equation string, like `"A + B + C + 4D"`, and place the number 1 in front of all variables that have no number in front of them. So something like:

```
>>> foo_eqn = "A + B + C + 4D"
>>> bar_eqn = fill_in_ones(foo_eqn)
>>> bar_eqn
"1A + 1B + 1C + 4D"
```

After some research and asking, I came up with

```
def fill_in_ones(in_eqn):
    out_eqn = re.sub(r"(\b[A-Z]\b)", "1"+ r"\1", in_eqn, re.I)
    return(out_eqn)
```

However, it looks like this only works for the first two variables:

```
>>> fill_in_ones("A + B")
1A + 1B
>>> fill_in_ones("A + B + E")
1A + 1B + E
>>> fill_in_ones("2A + B + C + D")
2A + 1B + 1C + D
```

Anything really obvious I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Short tip, use `r"1\1"` instead of `"1"+ r"\1"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `re.I` (ignore case flag) is the culprit:

```
>>> def fill_in_ones(in_eqn):
...     out_eqn = re.sub(r"(\b[A-Z]\b)", "1"+ r"\1", in_eqn)
...     return(out_eqn)
...
>>>
>>> fill_in_ones("A + 3B + C + 2D + E")
'1A + 3B + 1C + 2D + 1E'
```

This is because the next positional argument to [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is `count`, not `flags`. You'll need:

```
def fill_in_ones(in_eqn):
    out_eqn = re.sub(r"(\b[A-Z]\b)", "1"+ r"\1", in_eqn, flags=re.I)
    return(out_eqn)
```

Unfortunately, the `re.I` flag happens to be `2`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.I
2
```

Comment: [Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`. And it's because `re.I == 2`